# Why this React components causes infinite bucle renderization?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have this parent and child components:

```
function Child({initialValues, onChange}) {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = () => {
      const next = count + 1;
      const curr = [...values];
      curr.push(next);
      setValues(curr);
      setCount(next);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      onChange(values);
    }, [values]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const curr = [...values];
      initialValues.forEach(x => {
        curr.push(x);
      });
      setValues(curr);
    }, [initialValues]);


    return (
      <View>
        {values.map(v => <Text key={v}>{v}</Text>)}
        <Button onPress={handleChange}>Add</Button>
      </View>
    );
}



function Parent() {

    const [childState, setChildState] = useState([]);

    const handleMasterChange = (values) => {
      setChildState(values);
    };

    return (
      <Child initialValues={[4, 5]} onChange={handleMasterChange} />
    );
}
```

For some reason when I set the child state in my parent component it causes an infinite bucle.

If I remove the setChildState(values) function on the parent component it works fine.
Also if I remove the initialValues useEffect on the child component it works fine.
The problem is that I need both.
Any ideas? also any options to make this works fine?

Comment: What's an "infinite bucle"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the infinite loop caused by sending the `initialValues={[4, 5]}` as an inline property. I am able to reproduce the issue on my end.  It is resolved by memoizing the value using useMemo. Please change the parent component like below.

```
function Parent() {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState([]);

  const initialValues = useMemo(() => [4, 5], []);

  const handleMasterChange = (values) => {
    setChildState(values);
  };

  return <Child initialValues={initialValues} onChange={handleMasterChange} />;
}
```